# Is there a way in Powershell to provide virtual file systems in other file systems?

Tags: powershell, vfs, powershell-provider

I know you can write support for custom PSDrives. But those are always a root of a file system. What would be nice if there was a way to allow for VFS start at arbitrary nodes of the file system, such as using `Set-Location` to enter archive file maybe and use them as if they were folders. (Kinda like Far does this).

Is there any way to achieve this? I know, it would be some work to get it right and working, but at the moment I am more interested whether it would be possible *at all.*

**ETA:** What I don't want is a new PSDrive for every archive I enter, so the following isn't actually what I'm after:

```
PS C:\Path> Invoke-Magic stuff.zip
PS C:\Path> Set-Location MyNewDrive:
PS MyNewDrive:> _
```

but rather

```
PS C:\Path> Set-Location stuff.zip
PS C:\Path\stuff.zip> _
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is a FileSystem provider that also considers archives to be container objects. As [FileSystemProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.filesystemprovider(VS.85).aspx) is sealed, I think you would have to write your own [NavigationCmdletProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.provider.navigationcmdletprovider(VS.85).aspx) that does your magic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a [provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714460(VS.85).aspx), [here is an example](http://channel9.msdn.com/wiki/wiki/MSHVSSProvider/) for a provider for SourceSafe (old but still relevant)

Comment: The second link is dead, not archived in the Wayback-Machine, and searching for "MSHVSSProvider" doesn't yield any results that it could have been moved to.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  In fact, you can already do this to some degree without writing any snap-in code.  For example:

```
New-PsDrive -Scope Global -Name MyMod -PSProvider FileSystem -Root (split-path $profile | join-path -child Modules)
dir MyMod:\
```

Comment: The point is, I specifically *don't* want a new PSDrive but rather extending semantics for existing file systems. I'll update the question.

Comment: Looks kinda like `subst` to me what you're doing there, though.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you were asking for.